# Configuration object injection in Asp.Net Core 2.0.1 to multiple class libraries in solution

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-2.0

In a prior question I had asked about how to inject the whole Configuration object (defined in Startup.cs ConfigureServices)

```
services.AddSingleton(Configuration);
```

I did not get an answer specifically to that question but did figure out the proper way to access the settings in a class library. See the prior post 
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47459714/is-the-configuration-object-in-asp-net-core-2-0-injectable-in-a-class-library-p)

What I am trying to accomplish is have my infrastructure project capture all the configuration settings and then inject those settings in the constructors of any other classes that may or may not be defined in other class library projects in the solution, for example, in a unit test project or a services project.

I add the configuration classes in startup

```
 // Add our class objects so they can be injected
        services.Configure<ApplicationSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("ApplicationSettings"));
        services.Configure<LoggingSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
        services.Configure<ApplicationIconUrlSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("ApplicationIconUrls"));
        services.Configure<SmsSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("SmsSettings"));
```

But my database configuration settings are created in the infrastructure project based on the connection string type required.

```
public class ConfigurationSettings
{
    private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;        

    public ConfigurationSettings(IConfiguration config)
    {
        _configuration = config;
    }

    public DatabaseConfigurationSettings GetConnectionStringFor(DatabaseIsFor dbfor)
    {
        // the code to populate DatabaseConfigurationSettings removed
    }
}
```

And that all works fine, BUT I can't register this in Startup, at least I don't think I can, to make it inject-able. I want to be able to inject the Configuration singleton, defined in ConfigureServices to ANY other project within my solution.

That IS the question of this post, Is the Configuration object, defined as a singleton in ConfigureServices, inject-able to any other projects in a solution?

Because any time I try this in a class library project within the solution,

```
    private IConfiguration _configuration;

    public DatabaseService(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        _configuration = configuration;
    }
```

When I new up DatabaseService, for example in a test project, its requiring me to pass configuration to it

Comment: Both questions indicate that you don't quite understand how dependency injection works. Dependencies are injected only when you resolve class from container, not when you instantiate class directly.

Comment: @Evk...I am not a professional programmer, so no I don't FULLY understand DI, but I do understand how it works, it is implementing it I am struggling with. Please explain "Dependencies are injected only when you resolve class from container".

Comment: I tried to [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47462297/2630078) this in your original post in an update I made yesterday. [This](https://github.com/ninject/Ninject/wiki/Dependency-Injection-By-Hand) might be helpful (it's in the Ninject wiki, but nothing there is specific to that container).

Comment: @serpent5...Can we start with the basics, since I'm getting more confused as I go on. Does services.AddSingleton(Configuration); make Configuration available to the other projects in the solution? or is there another step to do so. All I really want at this point is to have that Configuration injected into other classes in other projects in the solution. I can't seem to get an answer to that.  Thanks for keeping along with this.

Comment: Or for that matter, the EF context created in ConfigureServices, how is that injected into your data layer project?

Comment: You can only get dependencies (like Configuration) be injected in classes you register in container (services here), not to arbitrary external classes.

Comment: @Evk... can I bind Configuration to a custom class of configuration settings and then register that class in services and have that injectable in my other projects? For example, a custom class with one property, ConnectionStrings and have that class’s ConnectionStrings property bound to the ConnectionStrings in app settings.json.